# What's a good F1-score in (not) extremely imbalanced dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, metric

I have a dataset with around 4.7K focused on binary classification. Class proportion is 33:67. meaning Label 1 is 1558 (33%) and Label 0 is 3154 (67%) of my dataset.

Is my dataset imbalanced? some people say it is not bad

My objective is **to increase the F1-score** only. I set the `class_weight=balanced` in my parameters and **`scoring=f1`** during CV as shown below.

```
svm=SVC(random_state=42)
svm_cv=GridSearchCV(svm,param_grid,cv=5,scoring='f1')
svm_cv.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
```

Can you let me know through a code sample on how I can increase the weightage to minority class? if that is any different from choosing `balanced` paramter

Currently my results are like as follows

[image]

I understand AUC for few algo is above 80 but I believe F1-score is more important for a imbalanced class problems like mine.

Can you help? I tried Oversampling minority class but not much improvement.

Increasing features doesn't take me to 80% F1-score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you data in not imbalanced. 33:67 is not a bad ratio but Try using under sampling of majority class. 
As another option you can try difference algorithms like randomforest. You can also try boosting.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sure. will try your suggestion. Upvoted for the help

Comment: btw i already tried different algorithms as you can see from screenshot

Comment: How many feature are there in your data? Have you tried confusion matrix?

Comment: Yes, but confusion matrix just gives the `TPR.FPR,FNR` etc. Yes, I did create a confusion matrix

Comment: I have 60 features in my data

Comment: Why don't you use all features? Why 6,7,9? Try using more feature it will help model in learning. Can I ask you did you selected that these 6 or 7 feature you will using in training?

Comment: I used all the features. And even then it doesn't return F1-score above 80

Comment: Try using correlation and variance to find best features. You can also try Neural network. I hope it will help you

Comment: I was experimenting with 6,7,9 features because through feature selection approach, I was able to see that just with these features, I was able to get an AUC of 82%. REST ALL FEATURES add only marginal/very minute improvement to the metrics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102367/discussion-between-ssmk-and-shahid-hamdam).

Answer (score 1):

I call imbalanced dataset is when you have a ratio of 90|10 at least. Your problem is not imbalanced.

F1 score is not a Loss Function but a metric. In your GridsearchCV you are minimising another loss function and then selecting in your folds the best F1 metric. It is important to understand these concepts.

If you want to apply Oversample/Undersample techniques you can use the following library. (Even if you don't need it)

https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/

If you want to improve your score you could try with another algorithm such as [Gradient Boosting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06951.pdf) with its different implementations XGB, LightGBM, catboost ...

Comment: thanks for the response. Upvoted